# How will Satan rage in the hearts of the children of men? (LDS perspective)

Tags: lds, eschatology, satan, good-and-evil, 2-nephi

The following passage from The Book of Mormon teaches that people will be strongly influenced by Satan in the last days, which Mormons believe are happening now.  Are there scriptural references or leadership comments that explain how this influence will be manifest?

> For the kingdom of the devil must shake, and they which belong to it must needs be stirred up unto repentance, or the devil will grasp them with his everlasting chains, and they be stirred up to anger, and perish; for behold, at that day shall he rage in the hearts of the children of men, and stir them up to anger against that which is good. And others will he pacify, and lull them away into carnal security, that they will say: All is well in Zion; yea, Zion prospereth, all is well—and thus the devil cheateth their souls, and leadeth them away carefully down to hell. ([2 Nephi 28:19–21](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/28.19-21?lang=eng&clang=eng#p18))

Answer (score 5):

The [Book of Mormon Student Manual](https://www.lds.org/manual/book-of-mormon-student-manual/chapter-13-2-nephi-28-30?lang=eng) quotes the following from a discourse by Richard C Edgley of the Presiding Bishopric. This is the best quote I've found that answers your question succinctly:

> We have … had very specific warnings regarding Satan’s power, influence, and determination. Nephi prophesied more than twenty-five hundred years ago of the trials and turbulence that you would face. You all know the scripture. It is found in the 28th chapter of 2 Nephi:
>
> [Quotes verses 20-21]
>
> I believe this scripture is true. I believe the time is now. And I believe the target is you. For the most part, Satan has made great strides in establishing and selling his value system... ‘Eat, drink, and be merry, for tomorrow we die’ (2 Nephi 28:7) and ‘There is no hell’ (2 Nephi 28:22). His is a value system based upon selfishness, self-indulgence, and immediate gratification... We see cultures infested with drugs, sex, alcohol, pornography, laziness, and many other spiritually devastating practices.

I think the main answer to your question is in those last few sentences. Those seem to be a few of the specific manifestations you are looking for.

You may also want to check out [this BYU website](http://scriptures.byu.edu/). It lets you look up all of the General Conference addresses that reference a particular scripture. Just look up the verses and you'll get a list of discourses that you can study that pertain to those verses. You may be able to find more information there, scattered across different talks.